# Android: Разрешение на использование Геолокации

Tags: java, android, геолокация

Есть приложение с использованием геолокации. В нем есть проверка на вкл/выкл разрешение на геолокацию. И если геолокация выключена - отправляет в настройки телефона вот таким образом:

```
  public void onClickLocationSettings() {
        startActivity(new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
    }
```

Но при тестах на Android 8.0 выяснилось, что эта уже не та настройка и геолокация для приложения включается уже в другом месте.

Вопрос: как универсально обратиться к "разрешению геолокации для конкретного моего приложения"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // делаем что-то, если геолокация не включена
    }
```

а вот код, чтобы предложить пользователю включить геолокацию

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного добавлю, у меня на Андроиде 10 появилась проблема, что в фоне сервис не получает доступа к местоположению.
Добавьте в манифест

```
<service
    android:foregroundServiceType="location"/>
```

и в разрешения

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Permission is not granted
// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION )) {
    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
} else {
    // No explanation needed; request the permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
}} else {
// Permission has already been granted}
```

//и нужно добавить в манифест

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java

Comment: душевный копипаст без объяснения. да и кажется мне, что это лишь проверка на вкл/выкл (которая у меня есть).